# React returning blank page when accessed directly from browser address bar

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is My App.js file where all the routes is defined.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Posts from './components/Posts'
import Login from './components/Login'
import { Home } from './components/Home'
import './assets/css/style.css'
import Layout from './components/Layout'
import Account from './components/Account'
import AppliedJobs from './components/AppliedJobs'
import About from './components/About'
import Contact from './components/Contact'
import { MultiStepForm } from './components/MultiStepForm'
import ForgotPassword from './components/ForgotPassword'
import ResetPassword from './components/ResetPassword'
import PrivacyPolicy from './components/PrivacyPolicy'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'
export const userContext = createContext() 
toast.configure()
const App = (props) =>{
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
      setAuth(true);
    } else {
      setAuth(false);
    }
  }, []);

  console.log('Auth Status',auth)
  
  let routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={()=> <Home auth={auth} />}/>
      <Route exact path='/job/:id' component={Posts}/>
      <Route exact path='/login' component={() => <Login setAuth={setAuth}/>}/>
      <Route exact path='/accout' component={Account}/>
      <Route exact path='/appliedjobs' component={AppliedJobs}/>
      <Route exact path='/about' component={()=> <About/>}/>
      <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
      <Route exact path='/Registration' component={MultiStepForm}/>
      <Route exact path='/forgot' component={ForgotPassword}/>
      <Route exact path='/reset/:id' component={ResetPassword}/>
      <Route exact path='/privacypolicy' component={PrivacyPolicy}/>
    </Switch>
  )
  return(
          <div>
            <Layout auth={auth} >{routes}</Layout>
          </div>
  )
}


export default App
```

When I try to access any route from direct URL, it shows me Blank Page. I have did tones of research on this but any solution didnt worked for me..............................................................

Comment: Do you have a `Router` component somewhere wrapping your app?

Comment: I have used HOC. I have one Layout component which wrapping all the apps.

`import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import PageFooter from './PageFooter'
const Layout = (props) => {
  return(
    <>
      <Navbar auth={props.auth} />
      {props.children}
      <PageFooter/>
    </>
  )
}

export default Layout;`

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Can you include all relevant code then?

Comment: @DrewReese Which else code you want?

Comment: I suppose I'm asking for all the components from `App` up to the one that I believe should be rendering a `Router` for your app, so that I may see how it is attempting to match paths and render pages. I'm asking for all the relevant code to produce a [Minimal, Complete, and ***Reproducible***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example.

Comment: This is my skype id live:.cid.91a248bf55e32cfb can we talk on that for better understanding.

Comment: @DrewReese can we talk on skype? This is my skype id live:.cid.91a248bf55e32cfb.

Comment: What @DrewReese wrote, please add all relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is solved by just changing the `<Switch>` to `<hashRouter>`.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you are authenticating `setAuth(true);` and passing props properly in Layout component

Comment: Yes everything works completely prefetch, But when I try to access any Route from URL bar it shows white blank page.

Comment: check if the auth state is `true` when you are accessing from url